# Android Java Array from Preferences

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop, sharedpreferences

In my Preferences I have a list of 10 mobile phone numbers.  Each Preference key is sms1, sms2, sms3, and so on.

My goal is to create a SMS or Message with multiple addressees to send to.  To do this, the to: string for the sms must be sms1,sms2, and so forth, all separated by commas.

I am trying to create a loop that will build the PhoneNumber Array that will be used in the sms to: filed.  TO do this, the loop should go through each sms key in the preferences and build the array.  I am not quite getting it right:

```
    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);

    String[] PhoneNumber = new String[12];
    for(int smscount = 1; smscount < 11; smscount ++){
        String RescueSMS = "sms" + smscount;

            PhoneNumber[smscount] = RescueSMS + ",";
            Log.w("MESSAGE", "SMS Array is " + PhoneNumber);
        }
```

The above code is actually pulling nothing accept a memory allocation string.  The "get" from teh preferences was so messed up that I had to remove it.  Got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Save data in sharedpreferences:

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
editor.putString(sms1, number1);
editor.putString(sms2, number2);

......

editor.putString(sms10, number10);
editor.commit();// commit is important here.
```

To retrieve it, you can possibly try something like:

```
String[] PhoneNumber = new String[12];
    for(int smscount = 1; smscount < 11; smscount ++){
            PhoneNumber[smscount-1] = (shared.getString("sms" + smscount, "DEFAULT NUMBER HERE"));
            Log.w("MESSAGE", "SMS Array is " + PhoneNumber);
            Log.w("MESSAGE", "SMS Array is " + Arrays.toString(PhoneNumber)); // This will give comma separated string by default.

        }
```

Note: The above loop would be similar to:

```
PhoneNumber[0] = (shared.getString("sms1", "DEFAULT NUMBER HERE"));
PhoneNumber[1] = (shared.getString("sms2", "DEFAULT NUMBER HERE"));
......
PhoneNumber[9] = (shared.getString("sms10", "DEFAULT NUMBER HERE"));
```

Comment: @Cybergei: Thank you so much... For now, you give me points by upvoting :)